# SQL Server : Avoid Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I want avoid sub-query in below query:

```
SELECT ID,[Start_Date],[End_Date],Assignment_Id 
FROM (
    SELECT ID, MIN([Start_Date]) AS [Start_Date], MAX([End_Date]) AS [End_Date]
    FROM EmployeeTable
    WHERE ID IN (123456) AND ([status] ='A' OR ([status] ='C'))
    GROUP BY ID, Assignment_Id 
    ) T
WHERE [End_date] >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120)
```

Please advice on above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120)`? Are you storing your dates as a `varchar`? (This is a bad idea.)

Comment: @Larnu Yes. Dates in this table are stored as varchar. At the moment, we can't do anything about it as it is the host system.

Comment: You can replace this code `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120)` with `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` to remove the time from GETDATE().

Comment: I suggest talking to your provider then. Storing dates as a `varchar` is a huge "no-no"; they should really be fixing that. If I were working with a software provider that used a `varchar` to store things like numbers and dates I would have huge misgivings about using their product; and probably look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, MIN([Start_Date]) AS [Start_Date], MAX([End_Date]) AS [End_Date]
FROM EmployeeTable
WHERE ID IN (123456) AND ([status] ='A' OR ([status] ='C'))
GROUP BY ID, Assignment_Id 
HAVING MAX([End_Date]) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your outer `where` clause with `having` clause immediate after doing aggregation and you don't need to use `OR` you can directly express it by using `IN` clause :

```
 SELECT ID, MIN([Start_Date]) AS [Start_Date], MAX([End_Date]) AS [End_Date]
 FROM EmployeeTable
 WHERE ID = 123456 AND [status] IN ('A','C')
 GROUP BY ID, Assignment_Id
 HAVING MAX([End_Date]) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

A HAVING clause in SQL specifies that an SQL SELECT statement should only return rows where aggregate values meet the specified conditions. It was added to the SQL language because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.
  by using `having` clause you can filter your data as you already used group by
    so you can easily use `having` ,@joe already  showed   in his query how to use that

```
    SELECT ID,Assignment_Id, MIN([Start_Date]) AS [Start_Date], MAX([End_Date]) AS [End_Date]
    FROM EmployeeTable
    WHERE ID IN (123456) AND ([status] ='A' OR ([status] ='C'))
    GROUP BY ID, Assignment_Id 
    HAVING MAX([End_Date]) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120)
```